# mat-error showing error for all form control when error in only one one field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am producing a table column with input field for Quantity with the following code

component.html

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let ind=index">
   <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input class="searchWidth" matInput placeholder="Quantity" [(value)]="row.ORD_QTY [formControl]="qty">
      <mat-error *ngIf="qty.hasError('pattern')">Quantity has to be of type Number</mat-error>
   </mat-form-field>
</td>
```

component.ts

```
qty = new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern("^[0-9]")])
```

Problem:
If there is error in even one of the rows the error will be shown in all the rows. How do I restrict error to only one line

---

[image: ?]

Comment: Could you please provide more details(code) or a StackBlitz sample for the same?

Comment: Bcoz all are having same formControl instance use FormArray

Comment: NOT use [(value)] and [formControl], if you want to give value to the form use setValue or: `qty = new FormControl(row.ORD_QTY, [Validators.pattern("^[0-9]")])`. BTW you has an unique FormControl that repeat severals times. If you want severals FormControls, use a FormArray